# Subclass recursive method call

Tags: c++, class, methods, recursion, subclass

In my FileProc class, I have four functions:

```
ReadFile(TemplateList<char> &ReadList){}
ReadFile(TemplateListAdv<char> &ReadList){}
ReadFile(CharList &ReadList){}
ReadFile(CharListAdv &ReadList){}
```

Which are all supposed to call a centralised method (which they are converted to):

```
ReadFile(TemplateListEditor<char> &ReadList){} //Contained by FileBasic
```

For background information, class hierarchy is as follows:

> TemplateList -> CharList
>   TemplateList -> TemplateListAdv
>   CharList -> CharListAdv
>   TemplateList -> TemplateListEditor
>   FileBasic -> FileProc

My issue is there is a recursive function call (where TemplateList converted into TemplateListEditor will keep calling the TemplateList function), despite the fact the classes are internally different. Typecasting does not seem to work. Without renaming the function (which would defeat the point as it's supposed to be universal), how do I make the  method look up the correct method?

(And I am surprised the compiler never flagged up an ambiguity resolution error for this).

Example:

```
const bool ReadFile(TL::TemplateList<char> &ReadList, const bool Recursion = false)
{
    printf("Is recursion true? %d!\n",Recursion);
    TL::TemplateListEditor<char> Temp(ReadList);

    //Calls itself instead of
    //const bool ReadFile(TL::TemplateListEditor<char> &ReadList, const bool Recursion = false)
    if(!ReadFile(static_cast<TL::TemplateListEditor<char> &>(Temp),true ))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above will ouput:

> Is recursion true? 0
>   Is recursion true? 1
>   Is recursion true? 1
>   etc

It strikes me TemplateListEditor (despite being static cast etc etc) is somehow or for some mind boggling reason, being converted back to TemplateList. Editor's constructors are all explicit.

Comment: Can you give an actual code example of what you mean?

Comment: It's a little difficult given it's embedded. I'll try. But basically, the compiler is somehow translating the TemplateListEditor, back into a TemplateList... aha... copy constructors aren't explicit... I hope they aren't... (Sorry, they are explicit. Same issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear.  But I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
class A { ... };
class B : public A { ... };

void readFile(A &a) { ... };

void readFile(B &b)
{
    readFile(b); // Recursive call
    readFile(static_cast<A&>(b));  // Non-recursive call
}
```

Function overloads are determined at compile-time, not run-time.  The compiler attempts to locate the best match based on the *static* types of the arguments.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I meant. I tried to make the example code but it didn't behave like the problem in the FileProc class. But this is what I mean. Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, B is being passed to a function that expects B, but B is being converted into A, which calls the A function that converts A into B so it can call the B function (which loops back on itself). The conversion is implicit so I had no idea how to get it to do it correctly. Arrgggh stress.

Comment: Sorry Oli, static_cast (like typecast) didn't work for me. It's still converting TemplateListEditor into TemplateList.